# QuickFix window default postion

Tags: split, quickfix

It seems that the QuickFix window is created on the bottom of the upmost right vertical split.

If I start with two splits:

[image: two buffer splits]

When I open the QuickFix window (`:copen`) the QuickFix windows is created as a horizontal split of the second vertical split:

[image: two buffer split and the QuickFix]

I would like that it opens at the bottom of the vertical splits:

[image: QuickFix at the bottom]

Is there a way to configure Vim to have such behavior?

Comment: This annoyed me to know end. And I kept (still do) forgetting to add `bot` to `:cw`. Need to add a mapping I guess (but I am too used to `:cw` after five years!).

Comment: @3N4N No need to change your habits: `:cabbrev <expr> cw getcmdline() == 'cw' ? 'bot cw' : 'cw'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bot copen
```

Don't have anything to add to it.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6728687

Quickfix window will automatically open in the bottom.

```
:autocmd FileType qf wincmd J
```

**Update**
One issue with above is, `vert copen` no longer works. (i.e. trying to open quickfix in a vertical split). In those cases, use `Ctrl w L` to move it to vertical split